# What is dot in ls -l command on Linux?

Tags: linux, centos, ls

I ran `ls -l` on my `centOS 6.10` on a specific file.

My question is what is the meaning of this dot(`.`) before `1`?

```
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  575 Oct 23
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means that the file has an SELinux context. Use `ls -Z` to see the actual SElinux context values. It's documented on the "info" file for GNU Coreutils: [What-information-is-listed](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/What-information-is-listed.html#What-information-is-listed).

The relevant quote:

```
 Following the file mode bits is a single character that specifies
 whether an alternate access method such as an access control list
 applies to the file.  When the character following the file mode
 bits is a space, there is no alternate access method.  When it is a
 printing character, then there is such a method.

 GNU ‘ls’ uses a ‘.’ character to indicate a file with a security
 context, but no other alternate access method.

 A file with any other combination of alternate access methods is
 marked with a ‘+’ character.
```

Follow the [link](https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=1060#top) for more details